# X display, Ubuntu server

Tags: server, display, raspberrypi, browser

I have Ubuntu server installed on a Raspberry Pi. I need to run `chromium` on it, but I keep getting this error message:

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
Unable to open X display.
```

How can I fix this? Can it be fixed if I install the VNC server on my Ubuntu Raspberry Pi, and go from there?

Comment: How does installing VNC a remote access protocol fix a Xserver display issue? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to run nodeJS and a module called puppeter. So I can scrape some webpages. And therefore I need to run chronium on my webserver. 

Sorry but totally newbie with this and only google around and read about VNC server, but doesnt not know exactly what I m doing..

Comment: Still does not come close to why you thing VNC can fix it.

Comment: You have not said much about your setup but it sounds like you are attempting to run a graphical GUI application on a server with no GUI, which is why you are getting the error - there is no X windows (X11) running on your server which is why you get the `unable to open X display`. You would have to install it. VNC would also require a GUI installed.

Comment: Yes, I dont have an GUI. Only running ubuntu server on a raspberry pie in my basement, and just want it to be able to use Chromium on it for webscraping. 
I have tried,  to install X display, and changed the setupfile, and logged in with ssh -X user.. But got the same error.